# What does it mean when a file appears gray in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

The red file name means that you don't submit the file to the svn. But what does it mean when the file name's color is gray?

[image]

Comment: Check the standard colors here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/file-status-highlights.html

Answer (score 2):

Are you using [.ignore](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7495--ignore) plugin? When it's enabled, files added to `.gitignore` are colored this way. 
If no custom plugins are used, the color likely means that file is scheduled for deletion from the repository